# Calculate days to go until a particular date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to count down the days until a particular event using momentjs but I'm getting an unexpected result.

With today's date being 17th April, and the event date being 14th May, I want the resulting number of days to be 27, however my code gives me a result of 57. What's wrong?

```
function daysRemaining() {
    var eventdate = moment([2015, 5, 14]);
    var todaysdate = moment();
    return eventdate.diff(todaysdate, 'days');
}
alert(daysRemaining());
```

Comment: If you run `console.log(eventdate.format());`, it returns `"2015-06-14T00:00:00-04:00"`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When creating a moment object using an array, you have to take note that months, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds are all zero indexed. Years and days of the month are 1 indexed. This is to mirror the native `Date` parameters.

[Reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/)

So either change the month to 4 to reflect May or parse the date as an [ISO 8601 string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

```
function daysRemaining() {
    var eventdate = moment("2015-05-14");
    var todaysdate = moment();
    return eventdate.diff(todaysdate, 'days');
}
alert(daysRemaining());
```

Comment: That assumes UTC.  What about the local timezone?  For example, the above code with the event date set to 12/25/2019 with today being 11/27/2019 @ 10:27PM ET returns 27 days when it's actually 28 days.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add for anyone else that comes across this - there's actually a helper that does the phrasing etc for you:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/

```
/* Retrieve a string describing the time from now to the provided date */
daysUntil: function(dateToCheckAgainst){
    return new moment().to(moment(dateToCheckAgainst));
}

// Sample outputs
"in three months"
"in two months"
"in 25 days"
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because months are zero indexed. So 5 is actually June ;)

Comment: Ok, that wasn't the answer I was expecting! What about the day and year?

Comment: [Reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/) - "Because this mirrors the native Date parameters, months, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds are all zero indexed. Years and days of the month are 1 indexed."